# How to fill ndarray in a diagonal way?

Tags: numpy

I want to create a certain ndarray, shape is (a, b, c, b). If index of the second dimension equals the index of the latest dimension, set it to 1, otherwise 0.

I wrote the following snippet, it works. Is there a more elegant, more efficient way?

```py
import numpy as np

a, b, c = 2, 3, 5
arr = np.zeros((a, b, c, b))
l = list(range(b))
arr[:, l, :, l] = 1
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may broadcast an eye array [2]:

```
arr = np.empty((a, b, c, b))
arr[:] = np.eye(b)[None, :, None, :]
```

If you want everything in a single line, you can tile an eye array and reshape it [3]:

```
arr = np.tile(np.eye(b), reps=(a,c)).reshape((a, b, c, b))
```

Timings (yours is [1]):

```
[1] 3.14 µs ± 46.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
[2] 1.82 µs ± 21.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
[3] 4.5 µs ± 47 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```